# SQL query - how to construct multiple SUMs (based on different parameters) in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please review my tables below... Is it possible to build a **single** query capable of
 
**1)** calculating the SUM of total_time for all vehicles that have class_id 1 (regardless of feature_id)
(result would be 6:35) 
**2)** calculating the SUM of total_time for all vehicles that have class_id 1 AND have feature_id 2
(result would be 5:35 based on vehicle_id 22 and 24)

I'm able to get the results in two seperate queries, but I was hoping to retrieve them in one single query.... something like:

```
SELECT 
    SUM((CASE WHEN (VEHICLE_TABLE.class_id = 1) then LOG_TABLE.total_time else 0 end)) **AS TOTAL_ALL**,
    ...here goes statement for 2)... AS TOTAL_DIESEL...
FROM LOG_TABLE, VEHICLE_TABLE .....
WHERE VEHICLE_TABLE.vehicle_id = LOG_TABLE.vehicle_id ......
```

**TABLE 1: LOG_TABLE** (vehicle_id is NOT unique)
vehicle_id  |  total_time
--------------|--------------
      22               2:00
      22               0:30
      23               1:00
      24               2:20
      24               0:45
**TABLE 2: VEHICLE_TABLE** (vehicle_id is unique)
vehicle_id  |  class_id
--------------|--------------
      22                1
      23                3
      24                1
**TABLE 3: VEHICLE_FEATURES_TABLE** (vehicle_id is NOT unique but feature_id is unique per vehicle_id)
vehicle_id  |  feature_id
--------------|--------------
      22                1
      22                2
      23                1
      23                2
      23                6
      24                2
      24                6

Comment: why dont you try only get all data and make the sums on code? personally I try to avoid all kind of sums and functions that would make my dbms get slow

Comment: An efficient query won't make your database run slow. That's the whole point. Your application will run slow retrieving all the data as opposed to only what you need.

Comment: You are doing it in a single query. Why do you call it two separate queries? I mean you solved it already.

Comment: @Clodoaldo  No I'm not. My example query only retrieves number 1) of my desired results. It doesn't get number 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  SUM(lt.total_time) AS TOTAL_ALL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (vft.feature_id IS NOT NULL) then LOG_TABLE.total_time else 0 end) AS FEATURE_TOTAL

FROM    VEHICLE_TABLE vt

        JOIN LOG_TABLE lt
        ON vt.vehicle_id = lt.vehicle_id

        LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_FEATURES_TABLE vft
        ON vt.vehicle_id = vft.vehicle_id AND vft.feature_id = 2

WHERE   vt.class_id = 1
```

Comment: WOW I'm impressed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not much point in putting both of them in one query unless you want the results together.
If so, just add a UNION between the 2 queries.

If you want to have both values in the same row try something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT Sum(X) 
        FROM   TBL 
        WHERE  CLASS_ID = 1)       AS CLS_id1, 
       (SELECT Sum(X) 
        FROM   TBL 
        WHERE  CLASS_ID = 1 
               AND FEATURE_ID = 2) AS CLS_id1_FTR_ID2
```

Comment: Yes, I do want the results together as two columns. A union will indeed yield the results but in one column as two separate rows. Not what I am looking for. Thx.